# if then logic failing to execute code block

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net-4.5

I have the following code logic in my vb.net(.net 4.7) page that is supposed to check the value of a session object.

If that object is not nothing and that object does not equal a specific string, then the code block between the if and end if statements is supposed to be executed.

But no matter what I do, it never gets executed.

I even tried setting a breakpoint in Visual Studio to see what the value of Session("buildingID") is, and even if it's something like this:

```
Session("buildingID") = "991c"
```

The code block is never hit.

Here is the logic:

```
If Session("buildingID") IsNot Nothing AndAlso Not Session("buildingID").ToString = "543a" Then
    'Do Stuff
End If
```

The Session object is of type

> System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState

What could be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Not familiar with VB but do you need double equals sign `==`? `=` is an assignment in C#, `==` is a check/comparison.

Comment: @wazz tried that but it gave me a syntax error.  I do know what you mean though because I've done that in c#

Comment: I don't see any problem in your code. I would suggest to analyze it more like try using this at first `If Session("buildingID").ToString <> "543a" Then`

Comment: You didn't say what the original type is so I'll say you could fix it by doing If Not Session("buildingID").Equals("") AndAlso Not Session("buildingID").ToString.Equals("543a")

Comment: @CruleD the Session object is of type System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState

Comment: What if you say Session.Item("buildingID") = "991c" ?

Comment: What if you check for Session being nothing by using `IsNothing(Session("BuildingID")` Instead?

Comment: @wazz In vb a single `=` is used in both cases :)